# UIPageControl --To go to specific dot?

Tags: iphone

i have two questions,

1) If i have 10 dots (UIPageControl) and i want to directly go on any specific dot say 5 from from 1 without traveling through 2 to 4.  How i'll do that?

2)& Is it possible to travel automatically through dots, like after 2 min view will change with dots without user interaction (like we see in advertisements)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `pageControl.currentPage = 5`
2. Yes you need to set an NSTimer.

   ```
   myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(changeDot:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
   ```

Edit:

[NSTimer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Do you have implemented the changeDot method? Do you declare the timer? Do you fire the nstimer?

Answer (score 6):

I know its been awhile. But I will give my solution, just for the record.

Using a UIPageControl, I was trying to jump to a page, by taping on a dot.
To do that, in a UIPageControl subclass I add a touch handler:

`- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

and by knowing the size of each dot, calculate the index of the dot that was taped -> page.
As added the touch handler, the selector to `UIControlEventValueChanged` stoped working, so just call:
`- (void)sendActionsForControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents` check it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/sendActionsForControlEvents%3a)

Nothing difficult, it ends up with something like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    float dotSize = self.bounds.size.width / (self.numberOfPages + 2);
    int jumpToPage = (int)touchPoint.x / dotSize;
    self.currentPage = jumpToPage;
    [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}
```

Comment: Hi Sasho! I see that you edited my answer. May I ask you why? why add "2" to number of pages?? Like that the dot size is not correct, I think. Explain please. Thanks

Comment: Hi Frade, Just saw your comment. I have almost forgotten what I did then.
My reasoning was something like that: I think dots are not taking the the exact pagecontrol's width. They have some space between them including space on the left side of the first dot and space on the right side of the last dot (counting from left to right).
Anyway it worked precisely in my case with adding "2" and was not so precise with the original source.
Should you find my edit inapropriate please feel free to edit back.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) The underlying view is a scroll view, right? Then you can set the contentOffset in code.

2) You can create a scheduled timer which changes the contentOffset.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, it is not possible (see the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html)):

> The page control advances only one
>   page in either direction.

As for the second one, you should just set up a timer.

Answer (score 0):

Swift version of Frade's answer:

```
func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let touchPoint = touch.location(in: self)
        
        
        let dotSize = bounds.size.width / CGFloat(numberOfPages)
        let jumpToPage = touchPoint.x / dotSize;
        self.currentPage = Int(jumpToPage)
    }
}
```

Example of touchBegan function took from [hackingwithswift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-find-a-touchs-location-in-a-view-with-locationin)

Answer (score 0):

You can do with rx or protocol:

```
import UIKit
import RxSwift

public class SpecificDotPageControl: UIPageControl {
    
    //If you don't use rx, use a protocol here for detect that the currentPage is changed.
    public let currentPageChanged = PublishSubject<Int>()
    
    override public func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            guard let subview = self.subviews.first else {
                return
            }
            let touchPoint = touch.location(in: subview)
            let dotSize = subview.bounds.size.width / CGFloat(numberOfPages)
            let jumpToPage = touchPoint.x / dotSize
            self.currentPage = Int(jumpToPage)
            self.currentPageChanged.onNext(currentPage)
        }
    }
}
```

Example to use:

```
pageControl
     .currentPageChanged
     .subscribe { [weak self] currentPage in
         //Here you can change your page or collectionView page.
     }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```