# How to make pages on scrollview rotate automatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I have a scrollview and a page control added to it. The pages scroll horizontally on swipe event. But I don't wan't any user interaction to make pages scroll. I want pages to scroll automatically , like page 1 -> page 2-> page 3 and back to page 1->page2 and so on.

How do I make this change?

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694411/how-to-auto-scroll-uiscrollview-using-timer

Comment: It helped, but how to come back to page 1 once you scroll till page 3?

Comment: For that, You'll want to reset the content offset to 0 when it reaches a predefined limit (in this case, the end of the scrollView's content).  Of course, it will be a very noticeable jump if your content is large.

Answer (score 0):

For that see this link

[UIPageControl --To go to specific dot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095995/uipagecontrol-to-go-to-specific-dot)

u can use NSTimer for that solution.

Comment: Answers which just contain links are [considered bad practice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please summarize the content here (don't copy/paste) so the answer can stand on its own. If you don't you run the risk of your answer being removed, especially if the link ever dies.

Comment: thx 4 ur help dude...ll give the answers perfectly next time.